# Initial value problems with known solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to find a list of IVPs with known solutions to test my implementation of some numerical techniques.

The only one I know of is:

$$f(x,y)= y' =-\lambda y\;,\;\;\; y(0)=1$$

with the solution $$y=e^{-\lambda x}$$

Should I simply just create my own or are there known equations that are normally used to test the implementation of methods like Euler, Runge-Kutta, Adams-Moulton, Adams-Bashforth, etc?

Comment: As it stands, it isn't a differential equation. Sure you aren't missing a sign?

Comment: @Shahar sorry, I edited. Is it fine now?

Comment: This is a simple separable equation.

Comment: @Shahar I already have the solution for that problem. I'm asking if there are more examples

Comment: I mean you can google "separable ode's."

Comment: @Shahar ah, I see what you mean, thanks !

Comment: You could look at e.g. http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CEAQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopus4.kobv.de%2Fopus4-zib%2Ffiles%2F337%2FSC-97-68.pdf&ei=Fr__U7akLOWiigKyh4DQAw&usg=AFQjCNExYMcz262WK1sBwWpfDI3kAfnwCw&sig2=D8uI1HPcNG_awY5tUatJZQ&bvm=bv.74115972,d.cGE and references there.

Comment: Have you tried searching for ODEs? It's a well-studied field, and if you're looking for examples to test a program on then you should be able to get a bunch from 1st and 2nd year university textbooks, or course notes.

Answer (score 0):

The following system has the  limit cycle  $\dfrac{x^2}{4} + y^2 = 1 $

You can use the initial value $(0,1)$ , but just about any choice of initial condition will lead back to the ellipse.

$\dot x = -4y +  x(1 - \dfrac{x^2}{4} - y^2) $

$\dot y = x + y(1 - \dfrac{x^2}{4} - y^2) $

( this is a problem answered not long ago. I'll leave a link.)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904737/show-that-the-parameterized-curve-is-a-periodic-solution-to-the-system-of-nonlin